# Is it possible to use Android Backup Service to store images?

Tags: android, android-backup-service

When I use `android/com.android.internal.backup.LocalTransport` I have no problems to store images (`byte`[]) along with other text data.

When I try to uninstall and install dev app on a device I see blank images and the following error `SkImageDecoder::Factory returned null error`

The way I store an image file in JSON:

```
File file = new File(filesDir, pictureFilename);
jsonObject.put("pictureFile", file.toString().getBytes());
```

And that's how I restore them:

```
try {
    FileOutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    out.write(jsonObject.get("pictureFile").toString().getBytes());
    out.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
    Log.e(TAG, "Can not write pictureFile", e);
}
```

UPD. My [BackupAgent](https://gist.github.com/dVaffection/4aef5dbd837a6216f6aa)

Comment: When working with images, chances are that, if you are receiving errors, might be due to OutOfMemoryErrors. Search in you stack trace for something like that...look here if that is the case: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29430640/outofmemoryerror-while-decoding-and-encoding-base64-string-into-bitmap

Comment: I don't have `OutOfMemoryError`s and I don't decode Base64 strings into Bitmaps.